# MATLAB: Faster method of finding Discrete Fourier Transform

Tags: matlab, time, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to write a code in matlab that does basically the same as the build-in `fft` function. Hence computing the discrete fourier transform of any given input vector.

The transform is given by

```
%                    N
%      X(k) =       sum  x(n)*exp(-j*2*pi*(k-1)*(n-1)/N), 1 <= k <= N.
%                   n=1
```

Now I created my own code to do this, but the computational effort is about a factor 200 when I look at the computation times. Obviously I would like to reduce this.

Below the computational part of my code, where `y` is the output vector.

```
N=length(input_vector)

for k = 1:N
        y(k)=0;
        for n = 1:N
            term = input_vector(n)*exp(-2*pi*1i*(n-1)*(k-1)/N);
            y(k)=y(k)+term;
        end
end
```

Now I think the computation is heavy because of the `for` loops and the line with `y(k)=y(k)+term`, since this happens at all iterations. I reckon I should be able to make this smaller by either using vector/matrix notation or by using functions with dummy variables and then iterate these functions. But I don't know how to start this process.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to write your own `fft` code? Why can't you use the built-in function? It is very unlikely you will be able to write something better than the built-in function, but there is a comment I can make that should help your code.

Comment: The transform you provided is the [actual definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#Definition) of the DFT, but you should never implement it this way, for its computation time is O(n^2). The great idea behind the FFT (the FAST Fourier transform) is how the [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm) is implemented in a recursive way, making its computation time O(N*log N), which is much faster. If you just have to implement your own DFT, you should go for this algorithm instead of the sums in for-loops you are implementing.

Comment: @Thales, it is just for practise, therefore I do not want to use `fft`. But that algorithm is a bit too complicated for me at the moment I think. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: That is the problem with the definition of the DFT. Prohibitive computational time. Sorry, but you can't do much better than that. Your code will run slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [implicit expansion](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html) you can greatly reduce the computation time of your algorithm:

```
% Vector length
N = length(input_vector);

% Vectorized DFT algorithm
y = sum(input_vector.*exp(-2*pi*1i*[0:N-1].'*[0:N-1]/N),2);
```

There is however two downsides:

1. The vectorization will consume a lot of memory (since a vector N*N
   have to be created)
2. It won't be faster than the built-in function.

Comment: Ah, I did not know you could let N run from 0 to N-1 within one function without using some kind of loop. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the key here is to know that multiplying an array `[N*1]` by an array `[1*N]` will create a `[N*N]` array. Check the link in my answer if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.